# can't install both packages duplicity and python-gi

Tags: 16.04, apt, backup

Both packages duplicity and python-gi are no longer available in the repositories. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you in advance.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install duplicity python-gi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-gi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package duplicity is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'duplicity' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-gi' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Both duplicity and python-gi are indeed in the 16.04 repositories. Check your sources.

Comment: @user535733 That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it?

Answer (score 4):

Both duplicity and python-gi are indeed in the 16.04 repositories.

This kind of error generally occurs on a new install if you have not run `sudo apt update` for the first time yet, as the apt data base is still empty.